# trying to understand the sys_socketcall parameter

Tags: linux, system-calls

Can anyone explain what this line exactly does:

```
socketcall(7,255);
```

I know, that the command is opening a port on the system, but I don't understand the parameter.
the man-page says

```
int socketcall(int call, unsigned long *args);

DESCRIPTION
       socketcall()  is a common kernel entry point for the socket system calls.  call determines which socket function to invoke.  args points to a block con-
       taining the actual arguments, which are passed through to the appropriate call.

       User programs should call the appropriate functions by their usual names.  Only standard library implementors and kernel  hackers  need  to  know  about
       socketcall().
```

Ok, call 7 is sys_getpeername, but if I take a look in the man-page:

```
int getpeername(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);

DESCRIPTION
       getpeername() returns the address of the peer connected to the socket sockfd, in the buffer pointed to by addr.  The addrlen argument should be initial-
       ized to indicate the amount of space pointed to by addr.  On return it contains the actual size of the name returned (in bytes).  The name is  truncated
       if the buffer provided is too small.

       The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, addrlen will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.
```

I really don't get it. The function needs 3 parameter. how did the function get the parameter? what means the 255? has anyone an idea how the function is opening a port?

Comment: Just for background, are you actually using some sort of UNIX variant instead of Linux?

Comment: No, I'm using debian, fedora or suse.

Comment: `255` is generally not a valid pointer, so either a) that is the wrong `socketcall()` manual page for that particular function, or b) `255` is some sort of special sentinel value that is not documented in that manual page that causes the function to do something somewhat different.

Comment: What is the context of the call? None of the standard consumers of the libc socketcall are C code, and even then they're significantly more likely to use the constant value rather than the magic number `7`.

Answer (score 0):

Although Linux has a system call that is commonly called `socketcall`, the C library does not expose any C function with that name.  Normally the standard wrapper functions such as `socket()` and `getpeername()` should be used, which will end up calling the system call, but if for some reason it is necessary to call the system call directly then that can be done with `syscall(SYS_socketcall, call, args)` or using assembly.

In this case the application or a library that it uses (other than the standard C library) has most likely defined its own function called `socketcall()`, that is unrelated to the system call.  You should check that function or its documentation to see what it does.